# Does 1-dimensional numpy array always behave like a row vector?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am trying to get a good understanding on broadcasting rules in numpy, but I have noticed I firstly need to get a good understanding on what 1-dimensional numpy array is. I found multiple sources saying that 1-dimensional numpy array is neither a horizontal or vertical vector. From that I'd expect that it behaves differently depending on an operation done and other component of the operation. But I can't really find a case when 1-dimensional array would behave like a column vector. For example:

```
a = np.arange(3)
b = np.arange(3)[:, np.newaxis]
a + b
array([[0, 1, 2],
      [1, 2, 3],
      [2, 3, 4]])
```

which indicates that `a` behaves like a horizontal vector. On the other hand, if we add it to horizontal vector `b`:

```
a = np.arange(3)
b = np.arange(3)[np.newaxis, :]
a + b
array([[0, 1, 4]])
```

`a` still behaves like a horizontal vector. On the other hand `a` seems to be indifferent to transformation with `.T`. So my question is - does 1-dimensional numpy arrays always mimic the horizontal vector behaviour? If not, what are the cases when they behave like standard vertical vector?

Comment: You really asking about broadcasting rules, which apply to all arrays, not just 1d.  1d isn't a special case.

Comment: In `numpy` 'row vector' doesn't have a special meaning.  A (1,3) array is just a 2d array; (3,1) is another shape.

Answer (score 2):

What you just came across is known as right align property of numpy arrays. When you have a vector of shape `(n, )` and some other array of shape `(a, b, c, d, ..., z)` then numpy will always try to broadcast the vector to shape `(1, 1, ...., n)` and finally check if `n` is broadcastable with `z` (in other words, `z` is a multiple of `n`).

Now, if you don't want the behaviour, you will have to tell numpy explicitly, how do you want to broadcast with the other array with which you are operating by adding axis to the vector using `np.newaxis`. You can also use the function `np.broadcast_arrays` to get the broadcasted arrays.

For example,

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b = np.eye(3)

# broadcasts a to shape (1, 3) first
# adds the vector a to rows of b
# [[1, 0, 0]      [[1, 2, 3]
#  [0, 1, 0]   +   [1, 2, 3]
#  [0, 0, 1]]      [1, 2, 3]]
print(a + b)

# Tell numpy explicitly, how you want
# your vector to be broadcasted
# Now, a is first broadcasted to shape (3, 1)
# and the vector a is added to the columns of b
# [[1, 0, 0]      [[1, 1, 1]
#  [0, 1, 0]   +   [2, 2, 2]
#  [0, 0, 1]]      [3, 3, 3]]
print(b + a[np.newaxis, :])
```